# repeated FeatureUnion in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am learning Pipelines and FeatureUnions in scikit-learn and thus wondering whether it is possible to repeated apply 'make_union' on a class?

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import sklearn.datasets as d

class IrisDataManupulation(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """
       Raise the matrix of feature in power
    """
    def __init__(self, power=2):
        self.power = power

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return np.power(X, self.power)

iris_data = d.load_iris()

X, y = iris_data.data, iris_data.target


# feature union:
fu = FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[('squared', IrisDataManupulation(power=2)),
                               ('third', IrisDataManupulation(power=3))])
```

**QUESTION**
Any neat way to create the FeatureUnion without repeating the same transformer, but rather passing a list of parameters?

For example:

```
fu_new = FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[('raise_power', IrisDataManupulation(), 
                      param_grid = {'raise_power__power':[2,3]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move all the powers work inside a single custom Transformer. We can change your `IrisDataManupulation` to handle the list of powers inside it:

```
class IrisDataManupulation(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, powers=[2]):
        self.powers = powers

    def transform(self, X):
        powered_arrays = []
        for power in self.powers:
            powered_arrays.append(np.power(X, power))

        return np.hstack(powered_arrays)
```

Then you can just use this new transformer instead of FeatureUnion:

```
fu = IrisDataManupulation(powers=[2,3])
```

Note: If you want to generate polynomial features from your original features, I would recommend to [see PolynomialFeatures](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html), which can generate the powers you want in addition to other interactions between features.

Comment: many thanks for your answer! I'm practising with Pipeline and FeatureUnion options, so I tried to challenge myself. I like your idea, however I thought about creating a simple function (IrisDataManupulation) and then use it as many times as required - taking `power` out of the class.

Comment: @ArnoldKlein I'm sorry, I dont understand. My current implementation also dont have hardcoded `power`. Its just that its a list of values now. You can specify `IrisDataManupulation(powers=[2])` and it will still work.